# Data from parent site list displayed on subsite list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, web-part, sharepoint-addin, sub-site

I have a parent site that has a list of team members along with other data about their positions.  I would like to display this list in a subsite.  I understand that with SP Designer I can link a web part from the parent to the subsite, but how to I get the subsite to show the data contained in the parent site list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Without using SharePoint Designer**

you can achieve that via `Content Query Web Part` as the following

- Open your Page > Click on Add web Part > below Content Rollup > Add Content Query Web Part .
- Click to open the tool pane to edit
- At Query section,> at Show items from the following list: > click browse to `browse any list from any site below your site collection`.
- Select the list that you need from the parent site.

[image]

Although this method will achieve your goal to show a list from the parent site, unfortunately, it will need some customization (ItemStyle) to show your CQWP as List view, and to can do this check [SharePoint Content Query web part like a SharePoint List View](https://msftplayground.com/2011/01/sharepoint-content-query-web-part-like-a-sharepoint-list-view/)

**Using SharePoint Designer,** check

- [Display a SharePoint List from Parent Site in Sub Site](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/11/06/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/)
- [SP 2016 - Display list from Parent site in sub-site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226651/sp-2016-display-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site/226657)

Comment: Check also my detail article at [Display a SharePoint List from Parent Site in Sub Site](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/11/06/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/)